# Images not resizing with Paperclip and Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, imagemagick, paperclip

I'm using Paperclip and Bootstrap. I'm rendering some images but they are not resizing to the dimensions that i've specified. No matter what, they stay at 200x200px. One image is 193x193px but instead of resizing to the specified 100x100 it resizes to 200x200.

**paper.rb**

```
class Paper < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :articles

  has_attached_file :image, styles: {standard: "100x100#"}
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

 <% @papers.each do |paper| %>
  <div class="papers col-md-4">
   <%= image_tag paper.image(:standard) %>
   <h4><%= link_to paper.name %></h4>
  </div>
 <% end %>

</div>
```

Is this being caused by bootstrap?

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What do you have when `<%= image_tag paper.image(:standard) %>` is computed?

Comment: A quick way to find out if it's Bootstrap or not is to load the image directly and see its dimensions. Basically load the computed url from `<%= image_tag paper.image(:standard) %>` in your browser.

Comment: yea, so loading the computed urls just displays each image with the dimensions 200x200

Comment: Can you create a new paper and post logs here. Might be this is related to imagemagick. because paperclip uses imagemagick for image resizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```
 <%= image_tag paper.image.url(:standard) %>
```

Please look into it .. you missed `url`

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation

Comment: did you see there should be resize your image

Comment: so i think i've fixed it. must have been a combination of the missing `url` part and that i wasn't uploading new/refreshing the images after amending `has_attached_file` meaning that the original url was being used everytime. Thanks for the help everyone.